# How can I use EF5 in the nest website when EF6 in the root website

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have published web app A in the root directory and web app B in the /B.

A and B are not dependence.

A use EF6 while B use EF5

I got a series of error messages start at `duplicate 'entityFramework'`. How can I use 2 EF version in 2 URL ?

Thank you.

Comment: To be honest I don't think you can. Both sites probably share the same /bin folder?

Comment: Both site are from different solution and has each /bin folder. I place A in c:/wwwroot and B in c:/wwwroot/B.

Comment: Try taking a look at the accepted answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897890/can-one-iis-website-host-multiple-web-applications-of-different-asp-net-versions . Does it help? You'll need to mark the subfolder B as a seperate website in IIS if you have access to IIS. If you don't, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you @StevenLemmens for your comment. I have created 2 application pools for each web app (root and /B). But not work still got the error message.