# Conflict browser session to publish two projects ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC in the same IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Publish an IIS on a Win Server 2008 R2 two projects, a fact asp.net asp.net MVC and another. When the user wants to work with both applications at the same time in the same browser, entering one session closes the other application, how can I do to coexist both ?. Webs.configs detail settings:

Web.Config in ASP.NET MVC:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Cuenta/Ingresar" timeout="2880" />
</authentication> 
... 
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="300">
<providers>
  <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
</providers>
</sessionState>
```

Web.Config in ASP.NET:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="sesionSU" timeout="600">
  <providers>
    <add name="sesionSU" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
...
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="validacion.aspx" timeout="300" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: You bind the two applications to different urls in IIS: `domain.com/app1/home` and `domain.com/app2/home`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897890/can-one-iis-website-host-multiple-web-applications-of-different-asp-net-versions

Comment: Add different name attribute values to the forms tag in each project like so:  <forms loginUrl="~/Cuenta/Ingresar" timeout="2880" name=".ASPXAUTHAPP1" /> and <forms loginUrl="validacion.aspx" timeout="300" name=".ASPXAUTHAPP2" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add different name attribute values to the forms tag in each project like so:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Cuenta/Ingresar" timeout="2880" name=".ASPXAUTHAPP1" />
```

and

```
<forms loginUrl="validacion.aspx" timeout="300" name=".ASPXAUTHAPP2" />
```

Comment: Kofi effectively, put the name and tried in different browsers and have no conflict. Thank you!!.

Comment: Glad you are OK. All the best.